# What is benefit of partition in Kafka?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

So, let's comparable Kafka and RabbitMQ.

```
Kafka(Partition) = RabbitMQ(Queue)
```

Queue contains all messages like list.

What is benefit of partition in Kafka, why not use messages only in one partition?

**Is it only fore replication?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka is not a queue, you cannot have selective acknowledgenents, which makes it way less usable as a queue.

There is already a subject not so far from your question ( actually, it's more the reverse, why Kafka and not a queue) :

[Is there any reason to use RabbitMQ over Kafka?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42151544/is-there-any-reason-to-use-rabbitmq-over-kafka/56893164#56893164)

To complete, and to answer more your question, in the other hand, Kafka partitions permit an easy transparent scaling out, by just playing with the numbers of partitions for a topic ( that would fit the number of consumers in a consumer group).

Yannick

Comment: Does kafka confirm that message delivered to customer and consumer read message?

Answer (score 2):

If you have many partitions, when one partition goes down, you can still read from another (replication).

Also, many partitions mean higher throughput. Producers can produce faster and more. And consumers can consume more and faster (using Consumer group)

As your system gets bigger and bigger, you can just add more partitions without stopping your system.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Instead of partitions, they can designed to have just topics and there will be no difference in terms of scalability, replication etc.
I think the advantage with partitions is you can have many consumers in consumer groups which will allow us to split load dynamically because kafka itself will decide and assign partitions to the consumers.